# Calculate difference between schedule's end and next's start with MySQL or Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database with start and end times, like so:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | start |  end  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | 10:00 | 12:00 |
|  2 | 13:00 | 15:00 |
|  3 | 14:00 | 19:00 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I would like to see if the difference between 2 of these records (lets call them schedules for now) have a minimum difference. What I mean is 2 of these schedules can't overlap (like `2` and `3`) and also I need to validate a minimum difference between the end of one and the start of the next (which btw also solves the overlapping since the diff in that case would be negative).

Is there any way to achieve this only using SQL?

If there isn't, my app server is using Ruby On Rails (4.2, the latest), is there a performance-efficient way to do this using RoR? By performance efficient, I mean running for a few hundred records in under a second or two.

If that's any help, the database is the latest MySQL release.

I would appreciate any help or directions regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

You can see if any times overlap by doing a self join with a comparison in the `WHERE` clause. Your SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.id as table1id,
    t2.id as table2id
FROM
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2
WHERE
    t1.id <> t2.id
    and t1.start < t2.end
    and t1.end > t2.start
```

To check is there is enough time after the end of the event, you would change `t2.end` and `t1.end` to `date_add(t1.end, interval 1 hour)` and `date_add(t2.end, interval 1 hour)`

Comment: To understand why this works, just remember that time is (still) linear: an event cannot end before it starts! But don't use comma-style joins.